# Futoshiki Puzzle with the least amount of clue

Tags: logical-deduction, optimization, puzzle-creation, grid-deduction

You are supposed to create a new $5$x$5$ [Futoshiki puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki) with the least amount of clues possible, but this puzzle needs a unique answer. In other words,

> What is the *minimum number of clues* for $5$x$5$ Futoshiki puzzle having a unique solution?

Note that

> Each number and each sign is a clue.

Comment: If you're interested, there are the very similar [Mainarizumu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainarizumu) puzzles

Comment: NB: There are only 30960 possible solutions (up to some measure of equivalence) and 22600736 different ways of putting down up to 5 clues, so brute-force is entirely feasible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To provide a starting point: The following puzzle with 6 clues should be uniquely solvable.

> [image]

This was mostly found by trying out different strategies. The basic idea was starting with a chain of 4 signs to get 5 numbers. The chain was constructed to put the numbers in as many different columns and rows as possible to provide the most restrictions to the puzzle. This leaves us with a column and a row with 3 numbers already determined. For each of those a sign was added to be able to deduce the order of those two missing numbers while also providing a clue for one other number. Thus each of those signs immediately gives us 3 new numbers and are together enough to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of why those symbols at the specified locations (meaning how these are arrived at) would provide much needed clarity.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay I've added a small explanation how I came up with this solution. I have no proof that this is the best possibility. Let me know if the explanation is understandable.

Comment: You say "This leaves us with a column and a row with 3 numbers already determined." Surely your chain of four signs gets you 5 numbers with at most 2 in any column or row... Am I missing a logical step here?

Comment: @Chris With those five numbers we can deduce another 3 due to unique digits in each row/column.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I think I missed that when I was solving. ;-)

Comment: It would be interesting if there was another solution that generated a more "random" pattern (note that the solution to the above is symmetric along the upper-left to lower-right diagonal, and if placed next to itself, has 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 running diagonally in order, lower-left to upper-right)  Not a critique, by any means!

Comment: @RDFozz You can move the right sign one more step to the right or the bottom sign one step up and still generate a unique solution. While those solutions look slightly more random, they are actually just swapping the last two rows or columns. You could also move the starting chain around, but that gives you a permutation of the numbers. So unless there is a vastly different way to get a unique solution with 6 signs, you will always recognize that pattern.

Comment: This answer is actually the right one, 6 clues are the minimum number, you may also do it with a number given instead of a sign at between 1,4 and 2.4, F[2,4]=5.

Comment: @Oray It *seems* right, but how do you know it can't be less?

Comment: @Veedrac I know that from my code, I tried all 5 pairs, couldn't find any unique solution.

Comment: well done! very satisfying!